# Group data column side into single dataset in pig

Tags: group-by, apache-pig, union

I have data like

```
(1,a,null)
(4,b,null)
(7,c,null)
(1,a,3)
(4,b,6)
(7,c,9)
```

I want distinct value and its count for each column like

```
(1,2)
(4,2)
(7,2)
(a,2)
(b,2)
(c,2)
(null,3)
(3,1)
(6,1)
(9,1)
```

Where as first 3 records are distinct value and its count in first, next 3 records are distinct value and its count in second record and last 4 records are distinct value and its count in last column.

For this I am trying to group the values by columns individually like

```
x = load 'path/to/file' using PigStorage(',') AS (col1:int,col2:chararray,col3:chararray);
B1 = GROUP x by col1;
B2 = GROUP x by col2;
B3 = GROUP x by col3;

C1 = FOREACH B1 GENERATE $0 as col1:chararray,COUNT(x);
C2 = FOREACH B2 GENERATE $0 as col2:chararray,COUNT(x);
C3 = FOREACH B3 GENERATE $0 as col3:chararray,COUNT(x);
```

This is giving the data separately:
C1 result is:

```
(1,{(1,a,null),(1,a,null)})
(4,{(4,b,null),(4,b,6)})
(7,{(7,c,null),(7,c,9)})
```

C2 result is:

```
(a,{(1,a,null),(1,a,3)})
(b,{(4,b,null),(4,b,6)})
(c,{(7,c,null),(7,c,9)})
```

C3 result is:

```
(null,{(1,a,null),(4,b,null),(7,c,null)})
(3,{(1,a,3)})
(6,{(4,b,6)})
(7,{(7,c,9)})
```

But i want all the datasets data to be placed in single dataset as below **with out using uninon keyword**

```
(1,{(1,a,null),(1,a,null)})
(4,{(4,b,null),(4,b,6)})
(7,{(7,c,null),(7,c,9)})
(a,{(1,a,null),(1,a,3)})
(b,{(4,b,null),(4,b,6)})
(c,{(7,c,null),(7,c,9)})
(null,{(1,a,null),(4,b,null),(7,c,null)})
(3,{(1,a,3)})
(6,{(4,b,6)})
(7,{(7,c,9)})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read the data as lines and do a word count.

**Script**

```
raw_data= LOAD 'test3.txt' AS (line:chararray);
words = FOREACH raw_data GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;
grouped = GROUP words BY word;
wordcount = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, COUNT(words);
DUMP wordcount;
```

**Output**

[image]